# infinite discontinuity as limit approaches x and f(x) is defined

Tags: calculus, continuity

If $\lim\limits_{x \to c^-} f(x) = -\infty$, and if $\lim\limits_{x \to c^+} f(x) = \infty$, and f(c) = d, is there both a removable and infinite discontinuity or just a removable discontinuity? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There cannot be a removable discontinuity, as $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ doesn't exist (the lateral limits don't have the same value). So the discontinuity is not removable. It is infinite.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: You are welcome~